# Problem trying to retrieve same stash variable multiple times in same template

Tags: stash

I'm having an issue retrieving a specific stash variable more than twice on the same page. It appears that when I try and get it the third time, I'm seeing random content output that lives elsewhere on the page.

The template code I'm using is pretty standard:

```
{exp:stash:get name="st_variable_name"}
```

Is there a limit to how many times you can show the same variable on a page?

**Update:** After further investigation this appears to be linked to switchee. Somehow.

Here's the basic template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{exp:stash:get name="st_school_name"}</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="appheader">
            <h1>{exp:stash:get name="st_school_name"}</h1>
        </div>
    </header><!-- end header -->
    <div class="content" role="main">
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_4}" parse="inward"}
    {case default="yes"}
        <span>School:</span> {exp:stash:get name="st_school_name"}
```

In the above code, it's the last line where things are going wrong. I'm thinking it has to be to do with switchee because if I move that last line above the switchee tag the output is as expected, which suggests that it has nothing to do with the frequency of calling that specific variable.

Cheers

Jim

Comment: You probably need to add a version of your template code in order to help.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt Romans - I've added some template code.